# How to skip hook configurations for control sequences that don't exist?

Tags: tex4ht

How can we make `tex4ht` skip a configuration for a hook if the corresponding control sequence doesn't exist?

Suppose we have a `4ht` file that contains a configuration for `\chapter`.

```
\Configure{chapter}
  {<beginning of chapter>}   {<end of the chapter>}
  {<before chapter heading>} {<after chapter heading>}
```

but we are using our `4ht` file with a document class, such as `article`, which lacks `\chapter`. Then we get the following warning:

```
l.10 --- TeX4ht warning --- \Configure{chapter}? ---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default definition of `\Configure` command:

```
 \def\Configure#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx \csname c:#1:\endcsname\relax
     \:warning{\string\Configure{#1}?}
  \fi
  \csname c:#1:\endcsname}
```

the `c:#1:` command is defined by `\NewConfigure` for particular particular configuration and takes care of `\Configure`'s parameters. The problem is, if the configuration isn't defined, the parameters aren't handled and they end in the document:

```
...
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head>  ¡beginning of chapter¿ ¡end of the chapter¿ ¡before chapter heading¿ ¡after
chapter heading¿ <title></title> 
...
```

As the number of parameters for `\Configure` isn't fixed, but depends on declaration by `\NewConfigure`, it is not easy to handle this situation automatically.

Possible solution would be to declare the configuration in the config file in the case it doesn't exist yet:

```
\newcommand\DeclareConfigure[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx \csname c:#1:\endcsname\relax%
    \NewConfigure{#1}{#2}%
  \fi%
}
```

this command uses the trick for checking configuration existence and declares the configuration if it doesn't exist. First parameter is configuration name, second is number of arguments. Full example:

```
\newcommand\DeclareConfigure[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx \csname c:#1:\endcsname\relax%
    \NewConfigure{#1}{#2}%
  \fi%
}

\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareConfigure{chapter}{4}
\begin{document}
\Configure{chapter}
  {<beginning of chapter>}   {<end of the chapter>}
    {<before chapter heading>} {<after chapter heading>}
\EndPreamble
```

`\Configure{chapter}` takes four parameters, so we need to use `\DeclareConfigure{chapter}{4}`